# Laravel: Why user never received any mail?

Tags: php, laravel, email

I trying send an mail to user to remind them to used the modules. So, in db table i have created `last_used_module` column to trace the value which null or didn't used for 7 days. SO, anyone can help me?

```
foreach($ModuleAutoMail as $module) {
    // echo $module ->last_used_module;
    if($mail->condition_id=='3'){                        
        if(is_null($module->last_used_module)){ 
            $ableToSendMail = true;

            $last_used_module = Carbon::parse($module->last_used_module);
            $DeferenceInDays = Carbon::parse(   Carbon::now())->diffInDays($last_used_module);

            if($DeferenceInDays > 7){
                $ableToSendMail = true;

                if ((EmailSave::where('email_id',$email_id)->where('user_id',$user_id)->count()< 1)){  
                    $ableToSendMail = true;
                }

                if ($ableToSendMail) {
                    $mails = new EmailSave;
                    $mails->user_id = $user->id;
                    $mails->email_id =$mail->id;
                    Mail::to($user->email)->send(new Automail($mail));
                    $mails->save();
                }
            }     
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: do u got any errors in log ?

Comment: I didnt get any error

Comment: problem sol ved

Comment: happy to hear :)

Comment: Could you please write what have to done to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The `if` ensures that the inner code only runs if the `last_used_module` is `null`, but then you attempt to parse `last_used_module` as a date which presumably will fail as it's `null`

Comment: Sorry, I didnt understand. Can u tell me detail?

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach($ModuleAutoMail as $module) {
       // echo $module ->last_used_module;
            if($mail->condition_id=='3' ){   

               $last_used_module = Carbon::parse($module->last_used_module);
               $DeferenceInDays = Carbon::parse(Carbon::now())->diffInDays($last_used_module);

                  if(is_null($module->last_used_module)){ 

                      $ableToSendMail = true;

                  }
                  elseif ($DeferenceInDays > 7) {
                            $ableToSendMail = true;
                  }
                 else {
                      if ((EmailSave::where('email_id',$email_id)->where('user_id',$user_id)->count()< 1)){  

                         $ableToSendMail = true;
                                    }
                                }
                 if ($ableToSendMail) {

                    $mails = new EmailSave;
                    $mails->user_id = $user->id;
                    $mails->email_id =$mail->id;
                    Mail::to($user->email)->send(new Automail($mail));
                    $mails->save();
                }
             }     
         }
```